# Unbuffered Read from File--Ruby

Tags: ruby, unbuffered

I need a way to read from a file, but reloading the data from the disk each time. How can this be done, short of using `File.reopen` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`IO#rewind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-rewind):

```
fp = File.open('pancakes.txt')
s  = fp.read
# Something changes the first part pancakes.txt...
fp.rewind
s = fp.read # This reads again from the beginning
```

This does of course require a seekable file but that shouldn't be a problem if you're using plain disk files.

Comment: This will reload contents from disk? This file will be modified by other processes, and every time I read, I want the most recent data.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: Yes, it moves the read pointer back to the beginning and starts again with whatever is in the file. You can try it `irb` and you'll see.